# paranoia issue with ransack on applying filter

Tags: filter, ransack, acts-as-paranoid, ruby-paranoia

I am using

```
gem 'paranoia', '> 2.3.1'
gem 'ransack', '> 1.8', '>= 1.8.7'
```

and on applying the filter it is not working perfectly can anybody tell me what is the issue or do I need to add extra configurations to make paranoia runnable with ransack?

And without paranoia filters are perfectly working fine.

Comment: mention error here.

Comment: Already described ERROR is not coming but filters are not working I mean always empty array

Answer (score 0):

Adding 
    belongs_to :child, -> { with_deleted }
helps, but doesn't work for joins and eager-loading before Rails 5.2

Hope this will help.

Comment: Already doing the same way but it is not working for filters with paranoia